Whether we can use the dual Ramsey theorem to prove the finite Ramsey theorem?
The dual Ramsey theorem was firstly proved by Graham and Rothschild in 1971, it said that for  the natural number $d$,$k$,$l\in\omega$, there exists a natural number $m$ such that for each $d$-coloring of all partitions of $m$ with $k$ blocks, there exists a partition $Q$ of $m$ with $l$ blocks such that
$$
\{P\mid P\text{ is a partition with k blocks coarser than Q}\}
$$
is monochromatic.
And in 2013 Solecki proved that there is a generalization of both the dual Ramsey theorem and the Ramsey theorem.
I know that we can use the infinite dual Ramsey theorem to prove the infinite Ramsey theorem, so that I want to find a proof between two finite versions. Since we have Solecki's result, does it mean we can not prove the Ramsey theorem from the dual form. I'm really appreciate if you can tell me the answer or give me some hints to use the dual form.

I have found the related answer and re-write it. But my code is fail to display correctly. Here is the article I find it:  RonaldGraham&BruceLeeRothschild(1971). Ramsey’sTheoremforn-Parameter
Sets, Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 159, 257–292.
